# Symfony2 Sonata can't access dashboard with prod environment

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

Hello I'm using Sonata's Project to create some kind of admin dashboard.
It works fine in local with dev environment but when using prod environment it does not work.

I mean, when I try to access the url of my dashboard something like /editorial/admin
it redirects to login (which is normal) and when I try to log in it breaks all my session and can't log in anymore until I remove my cookies.

I can't figure out where the problem is, so I need some help.

**config.yml**

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: amqp.yml }
- { resource: elasticsearch.yml }
- { resource: redis.yml }
- { resource: sonata.yml }
 ...
```

**sonata.yml**

```
sonata_admin:
title:      MyProject
title_logo: bundles/MyProjectfrontendassets/images/logo/myproject-monogramme.png
persist_filters: true
dashboard:
    blocks:
        - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }
    groups:
        sonata.admin.group.news:
            label: News
            icon: '<i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>'
            items:
                - sonata.admin.news.advice
                - sonata.admin.news.buying_guide
                - sonata.admin.news.faq

security:
    handler:  sonata.admin.security.handler.noop

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.admin.block.search_result:
            contexts: [admin]
        # Your other blocks
        sonata.block.service.menu:
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
    # Base roles
    ROLE_BACKEND_USER:                      ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:                             [ROLE_BACKEND_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:                       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    frontend:
        pattern: ^/
        host: %frontend_host%
        request_matcher: myproject_frontend.request_matcher
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: frontend_login
            use_referer: true
            default_target_path: frontend_home
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        switch_user:  true
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: %backend_host% }
    - { path: ^/editorial/admin, role: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, host: %frontend_host% }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: %frontend_host% }
```

**routing.yml**

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /editorial/admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
        type: sonata_admin
        prefix: /editorial/admin
```

Comment: `%frontend_host% may be blocking.

Comment: I removed %frontend_host% and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide log files content too?

Comment: Then good luck. Because in `production` mode you can't know the error without looking at log files or `debugging`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. 
It was varnish's cache in prod environment which doing things with cookies and session with this route